# Can I use a view to work around bugs in connected components?

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I've a table with some entries (around 1k rows and 20 columns). I have to select some of the columns/row and print them in a page via a plugin. That plugin has a bug with the SQL concatenate function, so I thought to generate a view with the desired data and then print everything of that view via `SELECT * FROM view`

I've never used views before. Could this be a valid reason to use them or it could lead to an excessive server usage?

Comment: Working around a bug in other people's software is always a valid reason to use any legitimate feature of a product :-)